# How to do `PUT` on Amazon S3 using Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 with Python Requests (Python is v2.7.9 and requests is v2.7). Following the curl command which works perfectly:

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file img.png https://mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b89e187-26fa-11e5-a04f-a45e60d45b53?Signature=Ow%3D&Expires=1436595966&AWSAccessKeyId=AQ
```

But when I do same with requests, it fails. Here's what I have tried:

```
url = https://mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/6b89e187-26fa-11e5-a04f-a45e60d45b53?Signature=Ow%3D&Expires=1436595966&AWSAccessKeyId=AQ
requests.put(url, files={'file': base64_encoded_image})
requests.put(url, files={'upload_file': base64_encoded_image})
```

It fails with 403 and response I am getting is:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Then I ran curl in verbose mode:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.231.168.134...
* Connected to mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com (54.231.168.134) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.s3.amazonaws.com
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> PUT /6b89e187-26fa-11e5-a04f-a45e60d45b53?Signature=Ow%3D&Expires=1436595966&AWSAccessKeyId=AQ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 52369
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: 5lLCQ3FVrTBg2vkyk44E+MecQJb2OGiloO0+2pKePtxPgZptKECNlUyYN43sl4LBNe9f8idh/cc=
< x-amz-request-id: 636A24D53DEB5215
< Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 12:04:44 GMT
< ETag: "5802130d4320b56a72afe720e2c323a7"
< Content-Length: 0
* Server AmazonS3 is not blacklisted
< Server: AmazonS3
<
* Connection #0 to host mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com left intact
```

So then I added `headers`

```
headers = {'Content-Length': '52369', 'Host': 'mybucket-dev.s3.amazonaws.com', 'Expect': '100-continue', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.37.1'}
requests.put(url, files={'file': base64_encoded_image}, headers=headers)
```

I tried with different combinations of header, still it throws same error. Then I tried to send query parameters too:

```
payload={'Expires': '1436595966', 'AWSAccessKeyId': 'AQ', 'Signature': 'Ow%3D'}
requests.put(url, files={'file': base64_encoded_image}, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

It still fails and same error. I tried URL without query parameters and sending them as `data=payload` to requests, it fails with same error.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `boto` for your uploads?

Comment: Why don't you use [Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for the connection and communication between amazon services? It would be easier to work with it than with Curl Requests.

Comment: `boto` instance requires authentication and it defeats the purpose in my case. I generate an url, which is pre signed and anyone with that URL can do `PUT`. They don't need any AWS keys/creds. Now, for test cases I don't want to run `os.system(curl...` and I want to use library like `requests`. Even if `boto` worked without credentials, I still want to do it using `requests` and want to know why it is failing, where as `curl` works flawlessly.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect something faulty happens with url quoting inside requests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Engineers at [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2664) helped me:

```
with open('img.png', 'rb') as data:
    requests.put(url, data=data)
```

Comment: So, did they explain what was wrong in your original ? Use the "data" parameter ?

Comment: Ah, from your link: "The real problem is that I think your upload is going to be multipart/form-encoded, but curl is uploading the file directly. Try: requests.put(url, data=open('img.png', 'rb'))"

Comment: hmm. only opening with `open(...).read()` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Acording to [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) documentation you have pass the **files** argument to **post** method also need send the **key** name for S3

```
import requests

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<some-bucket-name>'

data = { 'key': 'test/test.jpeg' }
files = { 'file': open('test.jpeg', 'rb') }

r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
print "status %s" % r.status_code
```

Comment: Fyi, adding the files param stores that info also in the s3 object. Which might not be what you want. I faced this while uploading json files and they were no longer json on download.